# 1st Reboot after fresh Yosemite Install - Chime + Apple logo + status bar...then

Tags: macos, imac, install

status bar goes about 1/3 of the way and then it dissappers along with the logo and I get just the white screen.

When I boot into Safe Mode I have no audio and sometime the screen flickers.  I looks like it flickering rolling up the screen.  It's weird.

I've tried two different HD's and created to different USB installeation disks.
I've reset PRAM and NVRAM.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Which Yosemite? 10.10.0 ... 10.10.5 ? Anything below 10.10.4 & I'd suspect a "rogue" kext, something like TRIMenabler.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be a Macbook Pro from 2010 to 2012 that you performed the installation on? It sounds an awful lot like the motherboard issue that these models suffer from....